# Credible interval for difference in bayesian regression coefficients

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I want to determine the credible interval for the difference in regression coefficients from a bayesian model. Can I subtract the results from an mcmc/gibbs sampler for each of the two coefficients and determine the interval that way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is standard approach: first you conduct MCMC simulation, and then compete whatever you need on the samples. To get things like posterior mean, median, intervals, etc, you just use standard empirical estimators on the samples.